# bluebired promisify function not converted to promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, bluebird

is their any other way to convert in promise ?

```
var Promise = require("bluebird");
let findOneOrCreate = require('mongoose-find-one-or-create');
findOneOrCreate = Promise.promisify(findOneOrCreate); // not converted to promise
```

I used  like then in .then():-

```
        db.employee.findOneOrCreate({
                organization: model.organization.id,
                EmpDb_Emp_id: model.EmpDb_Emp_id
            }, model)
            .then((employee, created) => {
                if (!created) {
                    throw 'employee already exist';
                }
                return employee;
            }).catch(err => {
                throw err;
            });
```

it gives an error: -

**Cannot read property 'then' of undefined**

Comment: `it gives an error` - what does? the code you posted? (not likely, you don't use `.then`) - are you sure you know what you're doing with promises?

Comment: `promisify` does not return a promise - it returns a *function* that when called returns a promise. Where do you call it?

Comment: That `mongoose-find-one-or-create` module is flawed (race conditions), you should consider using the built-in [`findOneAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-findOneAndUpdate) combined with `upsert : true`. Which also means you don't have to promisify anything, since Mongoose supports promises [out of the box](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html).

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, according to [bluebird documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisify.html) ,

> the node function should conform to node.js convention of accepting a
>   callback as last argument

[mongoose-find-one-or-create](https://github.com/beeplove/mongoose-find-one-or-create/blob/develop/index.js) accepts only `schema` as an argument, and extends this schema with `findOneOrCreate` function. So it seems that `require('mongoose-find-one-or-create')` cannot be promisified. You may try promisifying `findOneOrCreate` of an extended schema instead:

```
var findOneOrCreate = require('mongoose-find-one-or-create');
var PersonSchema = mongoose.Schema({...});
PersonSchema.plugin(findOneOrCreate);
var Person = mongoose.model('Person', PersonSchema);
var findOneOrCreatePromise = Promise.promisify(Person.findOneOrCreate);
```

Also keep in mind that `Promise.promisify()` returns a function, so you'll need to invoke it before calling `then`:

```
findOneOrCreatePromise().then(...)
```

not just

```
findOneOrCreatePromise.then(...)
```

Comment: it is converted into promise but it is not working fine .. and i try with callback fuctions it is working aud there